# Extend Individual Menu on Page Function to individual Submenue on Page Function?

Tags: menus

It seems that WordPress Development is building a knowledge-base about the best functions out there. Thanks a bunch this helped already a lot!

I found a function (find it down here) that offers a simple menu decision in a box for each page of your wordpress theme. A magic bag trick, kudos to H Peter Pfeufer!

but how does it work to just change the sub-header-menu in the sub-header-menu- theme position and not all menues on page with is nonsense.

As the function returns $args I wonder how to tell Wp that i just want them to change menu in sub-header-menu position. Do you have an idea or other Function,
Would be big!

```
/**
 * Erstellt eine Meta Box um einer Seite ein eigenes Menü mit zu geben.
 * Die Menüs müssen unter Design -> Menü definiert sein.
 *
 * @author H.-Peter Pfeufer
 */
if(!class_exists('Page_Menu_Meta_Box')) {
    class Page_Menu_Meta_Box {
        private $textdomain = 'meine-textdomain';   // Textdomain für die Übersetzung
        private $posttype = 'page';                 // Posttype (hier page für Seiten)
        private $metaname = 'page_menu';            // Name des Custom Fields
        private $metaboxID = 'page_menu';           // ID der Metabox
        private $noncename = 'page_menu';           // Name des Nonce (etwas für die Sicherheit
        private $defaultmenu = 'default';           // "Slug" des Standardmenüs
        private $userright = 'edit_page';           // Nutzerrechte die benötigt werden
        private $selectname = 'page-menu';          // Name des Selectferldes

        /**
         * Constructor (old style)
         *
         * @uses __construct
         */
        function Page_Menu_Meta_Box() {
            self::__construct();
        } // END function Page_Menu_Meta_Box()

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function __construct() {
            // Backend
            if(is_admin()) {
                add_action('add_meta_boxes', array(
                    &$this,
                    '_add_meta_box'
                ));

                add_action('save_post', array(
                    &$this,
                    '_save_page_menu'
                ));
            } // END if(is_admin())

            // Frontend
            if(!is_admin()) {
                add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', array(
                    &$this,
                    '_menu_per_page'
                ));
            } // END if(!is_admin())
        } // END function __construct()

        /**
         * Metabox am System anmelden
         */
        function _add_meta_box() {
            add_meta_box($this->metaboxID, __('Select the menu for this page', $this->textdomain), array(
                &$this,
                'the_meta_box'
            ), $this->posttype, 'normal', 'high');
        } // END function _add_meta_box()

        /**
         * Metabox erstellen
         */
        function the_meta_box() {
            global $post;

            // Menüs abholen
            $menues = wp_get_nav_menus();

            if(!empty($menues) && count($menues) != 0) {
                // Use nonce for verification
                wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $this->noncename);

                // Ist bereits ein Menü gewählt?
                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname, true);

                // Setting the defaultmenu
                if(empty($menuslug)) {
                    $menuslug = $this->defaultmenu;
                } // END if(empty($menu_name))

                echo sprintf('<p>%1$s</p>', __('Please select the menu which should be displayed on this page.', $this->textdomain));
                echo '<select name="' . $this->selectname . '">';

                foreach($menues as $menu) {
                    if(!empty($menuslug)) {
                        $selected = '';

                        if($menuslug == $menu->slug) {
                            $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                        } // END if($menu_name == $menu->slug)
                    } // END if(!empty($menu_name))

                    echo '<option value="' . $menu->slug . '"' . $selected . '>' . $menu->name . '</option>';
                } // END foreach($menues as $menu)

                echo '</select>';
            } // END if(!empty($menues) && count($menues) != 0)
        } // END function the_meta_box()

        /**
         * Daten speichern
         *
         * @param int $post_id
         */
        function _save_page_menu($post_id) {
            // Erst mal schauen wir, ob der Nutzer das überhaupt darf
            if(!current_user_can($this->userright, $post_id)) {
                return;
            }

            // Dann prüfen wir die Nonces
            if(!isset($_REQUEST[$this->noncename]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$this->noncename], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
                return;
            } // END if(!isset($_REQUEST['vokabel_page_menu']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['vokabel_page_menu'], plugin_basename(__FILE__)))

            // und nun wird der ganze Hokuspokus gespeichert
            $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_ID'];

            // Metainformationen hinzufügen oder aktualisieren
            add_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname, $_REQUEST[$this->selectname], true) or update_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname, $_REQUEST[$this->selectname]);
        } // END function _save_page_menu($post_id)

        /**
         * Menü im Frontend anzeigen
         *
         * @param array $args
         * @return Ambigous <mixed, string, multitype:, boolean, array, string>
         */
        function _menu_per_page($args = '') {
            if(is_page()) {
                global $post;

                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname, true);

                if(!empty($menuslug) && is_nav_menu($menuslug)) {
                    $args['menu'] = $menuslug;
                } // END if(!empty($menu_name) && is_nav_menu($menu_name))
            } // END if(is_page())

            return $args;
        } // END function _menu_per_page($args = '')
    } // END class Page_Menu_Meta_Box

    // Klasse starten
    new Page_Menu_Meta_Box();

} // END if(!class_exists('Page_Menu_Meta_Box'))
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Besides there is a lot of German in there, I incidentally can read it, but generally things should be in English, because it is the common denominator language-wise. Although the code speaks for itself of course.

Comment: Regarding your question, do you mean »sub-header-menu« is the value you want for the `theme_location` parameter for the `wp_nav_menu()` call? And, one more addition, you probably should link to the source too.

Comment: Yes »sub-header-menu« is the value I want for the theme_location parameter for the wp_nav_menu() call?

Comment: The Source: it is this Site: http://www.mdw.ac.at/filmakademie/de/

Comment: Where can i publish the Function again without German? Here in the comment section it is to long, thanks Thomas

Comment: I would say just [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/162735/edit) your question and replace the German explanations with English ones. Like I said the code speaks for itself, but it would be a nice thing to do, because optimally the questions and answers on here will help many other people. I think you misunderstood my source request, I thought actually more about the source of the code you are using, so probably the site of H.-Peter Pfeufer.

Comment: this was the original function...  http://ppfeufer.de/spass-mit-den-custom-menues-von-wordpress/   thanks for your investigation. cause now i found another source there what might be the solution.. they wrote a plug in! https://wordpress.org/plugins/ce-wp-menu-per-page/ will test it.. tho

Comment: I've updated the answer. Can you please add the additional information to your question - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about specifying your `$theme_location` for `wp_nav_menu()`, than it should be enough to check if it is the right location. And only than modify the `$args` of the `_menu_per_page()` function, which is used as callback for the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter. So the function looks like this:

```
    function _menu_per_page( $args ) {
        if(is_page()) {
            // the selected menu applies to the following location
            if ( $args['theme_location'] == 'sub-header-menu' ) {
                global $post;

                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname, true);

                if(!empty($menuslug) && is_nav_menu($menuslug)) {
                    $args['menu'] = $menuslug;
                } // END if(!empty($menu_name) && is_nav_menu($menu_name))
            } // END if ( $args['theme_location'] == 'sub-header-menu' )
        } // END if(is_page())

        return $args;
    } // END function _menu_per_page($args = '')
```

Comment: Yes, ialocin - that is exactly what i thought should work. But doesn´t. Tried it right now. Somehow the new $args are still written in all menues on page. Including the main menu, and sidebar menues which doesn´t make sense. I wonder how to exclude the other Menues.

Comment: Too bad, what if it is done like in my edit? @ThomasSchneider

Comment: Code in comments isn't a good match, please delete it. So the solution was to check for `$args['theme_location']`, like I suggested. @ThomasSchneider If you want to add your own answer, which you of course can do, then please add the complete code to it, because I see in the comments code you added code.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is now included in a plug in!

```
    <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: CE WP-Menu per Page
 * Plugin URI: http://ppfeufer.de/wordpress-plugin/ce-wp-menu-per-page/
 * Description: This plugin allows you to select a menu on a per page basis.
 * Version: 1.2
 * Author: Codeenterprise (H.-Peter Pfeufer)
 * Author URI: http://codeenterprise.de
 * Text Domain: ce-wp-menu-per-page
 * Domain Path: /l10n
 */


        /**
         * Constructor (old style)
         *
         * @uses __construct
         */
        function Ce_Wp_Menu_Per_Page() {
            self::__construct();
        } // END function Ce_Wp_Menu_Per_Page()

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function __construct() {
            // Backend
            if(is_admin()) {
                add_action('admin_init', array(
                    $this,
                    '_plugin_init'
                ));

                add_action('add_meta_boxes', array(
                    $this,
                    '_add_meta_box'
                ));

                add_action('save_post', array(
                    $this,
                    '_save_page_menu'
                ));
            } // END if(is_admin())

            // Frontend
            if(!is_admin()) {
                add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', array(
                    $this,
                    '_menu_per_page'
                ));
            } // END if(!is_admin())
        } // END function __construct()

        function _plugin_init() {
            /**
             * Sprachdatei wählen
             */
            if(function_exists('load_plugin_textdomain')) {
                load_plugin_textdomain($this->textdomain, false, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )) . '/l10n/');
            } // END if(function_exists('load_plugin_textdomain'))
        } // END function _plugin_init()

        /**
         * Metabox am System anmelden
         */
        function _add_meta_box() {
            add_meta_box($this->metaboxID, __('Select the menu for this page', $this->textdomain), array(
                $this,
                'the_meta_box'
            ), $this->posttype, 'normal', 'high');
        } // END function _add_meta_box()

        /**
         * Metabox erstellen
         */
        function the_meta_box() {
            global $post;

            // Menüs abholen
            $menues = wp_get_nav_menus();
            $menu_locations = get_registered_nav_menus();

            if(!empty($menues) && count($menues) != 0) {
                // Use nonce for verification
                wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $this->noncename);

                // Ist bereits ein Menü gewählt?
                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname_menu, true);
                $menuposition = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname_menu_position, true);

                // Setting the defaultmenu
                if(empty($menuslug)) {
                    $menuslug = $this->defaultmenu;
                } // END if(empty($menu_name))

                $array_DefaultMenu['wp-default'] = new stdClass();
                $array_DefaultMenu['wp-default']->name = __('Wordpress Default', $this->textdomain);
                $array_DefaultMenu['wp-default']->slug = 'wp-default';

                $menues = array_merge($array_DefaultMenu, (array) $menues);

                echo sprintf('<p>%1$s</p>', __('Please select the menu which should be displayed on this page.', $this->textdomain));
                echo '<select name="' . $this->menu_selectname . '">';

                foreach($menues as $menu) {
                    if(!empty($menuslug)) {
                        $selected = '';

                        if($menuslug == $menu->slug) {
                            $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                        } // END if($menu_name == $menu->slug)
                    } // END if(!empty($menu_name))

                    echo '<option value="' . $menu->slug . '"' . $selected . '>' . $menu->name . '</option>';
                } // END foreach($menues as $menu)

                echo '</select>';

                if(is_array($menu_locations) && count($menu_locations) != 0) {
                    echo sprintf('<p>%1$s</p>', __('Please select the menu location, where your menu should appear', $this->textdomain));
                    echo '<select name="' . $this->position_selectname . '">';

                    foreach($menu_locations as $slug => $position) {
                        if(!empty($menuposition)) {
                            $selected = '';

                            if($menuposition == $slug) {
                                $selected = ' selected="selected"';
                            } // END if($menu_name == $menu->slug)
                        } // END if(!empty($menu_name))

                        echo '<option value="' . $slug . '"' . $selected . '>' . $position . '</option>';
                    } // END foreach($menues as $menu)

                    echo '</select>';
                } // END if(is_array($menu_locations) && count($menu_locations) != 0)
            } // END if(!empty($menues) && count($menues) != 0)
        } // END function the_meta_box()

        /**
         * Daten speichern
         *
         * @param int $post_id
         */
        function _save_page_menu($post_id) {
            // Erst mal schauen wir, ob der Nutzer das überhaupt darf
            if(!current_user_can($this->userright, $post_id)) {
                return;
            }

            // Dann prüfen wir die Nonces
            if(!isset($_REQUEST[$this->noncename]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$this->noncename], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
                return;
            } // END if(!isset($_REQUEST['vokabel_page_menu']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['vokabel_page_menu'], plugin_basename(__FILE__)))

            // und nun wird der ganze Hokuspokus gespeichert
            $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_ID'];

            /**
             * Saving the Settings
             */
            if($_REQUEST[$this->menu_selectname] == $this->defaultmenu) {
                // Get the old slug
                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname_menu, true);

                if(empty($menuslug)) {
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu);
                    delete_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu_position);
                } // END if(empty($menu_name))
            } else {
                // Metainformationen hinzufügen oder aktualisieren
                add_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu, $_REQUEST[$this->menu_selectname], true) or update_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu, $_REQUEST[$this->menu_selectname]);
                add_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu_position, $_REQUEST[$this->position_selectname], true) or update_post_meta($post_id, $this->metaname_menu_position, $_REQUEST[$this->position_selectname]);
            } // END // END if($_REQUEST[$this->menu_selectname] == $this->defaultmenu)
        } // END function _save_page_menu($post_id)

        /**
         * Menü im Frontend anzeigen
         *
         * @param array $args
         * @return Ambigous <mixed, string, multitype:, boolean, array, string>
         */
        function _menu_per_page($args = '') {
            global $post;

            if(!empty($post)) {
                $menuslug = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname_menu, true);
                $menuposition = get_post_meta($post->ID, $this->metaname_menu_position, true);

                if(empty($menuposition)) {
                    $menuposition = $this->defaultmenu_position;
                } // END if(empty($menuposition))

                if(is_page() && $args['theme_location'] == $menuposition) {
                    if(!empty($menuslug) && is_nav_menu($menuslug)) {
                        $args['menu'] = $menuslug;
                    } // END if(!empty($menu_name) && is_nav_menu($menu_name))
                } // END if(is_page())
            } // END if(!empty($post))

            return $args;
        } // END function _menu_per_page($args = '')
    } // END class Ce_Wp_Menu_Per_Page

    // Klasse starten
    new Ce_Wp_Menu_Per_Page();
} // END if(!class_exists('Ce_Wp_Menu_Per_Page'))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the solution or main difference between question and answer code is the check for `$args['theme_location']` which makes it possible to apply changes to a specific location only.